# Attention matrix in Python with PyTorch

Tags: python, natural-language-processing

I want to implement Q&A systems with attention mechanism. I have two inputs; `context` and `query` which shapes are `(batch_size, context_seq_len, embd_size)` and `(batch_size,  query_seq_len, embd_size)`.

I am following the paper 
[*Machine Comprehension Using Match-LSTM and Answer Pointer*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.07905).

Then I want to obtain an attention matrix which has the shape of `(batch_size, context_seq_len, query_seq_len, embd_size)`. In the thesis, they calculate values for each row (it means each context word, G_i, alpha_i in the paper).

My code is below and it is running, but I am not sure my way is good or not. For example, I use `for loop` for generating sequence data (`for i in range(T):`). And to obtain each row, I use in-place operator like `G[:,i,:,:]`, `embd_context[:,i,:].clone()` is a good manner in pytorch? If not, where should I change the code?

And if you notice other points, let me know. I am a new in this field and pytorch. Sorry for my ambiguous question.

```
class MatchLSTM(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, args):
        super(MatchLSTM, self).__init__()
        self.embd_size = args.embd_size
        d = self.embd_size
        self.answer_token_len = args.answer_token_len

        self.embd = WordEmbedding(args)
        self.ctx_rnn   = nn.GRU(d, d, dropout = 0.2)
        self.query_rnn = nn.GRU(d, d, dropout = 0.2)

        self.ptr_net = PointerNetwork(d, d, self.answer_token_len) # TBD

        self.w  = nn.Parameter(torch.rand(1, d, 1).type(torch.FloatTensor), requires_grad=True) # (1, 1, d)
        self.Wq = nn.Parameter(torch.rand(1, d, d).type(torch.FloatTensor), requires_grad=True) # (1, d, d)
        self.Wp = nn.Parameter(torch.rand(1, d, d).type(torch.FloatTensor), requires_grad=True) # (1, d, d)
        self.Wr = nn.Parameter(torch.rand(1, d, d).type(torch.FloatTensor), requires_grad=True) # (1, d, d)

        self.match_lstm_cell = nn.LSTMCell(2*d, d)

    def forward(self, context, query):
        # params
        d = self.embd_size
        bs = context.size(0) # batch size
        T = context.size(1)  # context length 
        J = query.size(1)    # query length

        # LSTM Preprocessing Layer
        shape = (bs, T, J, d)
        embd_context     = self.embd(context)         # (N, T, d)
        embd_context, _h = self.ctx_rnn(embd_context) # (N, T, d)
        embd_context_ex  = embd_context.unsqueeze(2).expand(shape).contiguous() # (N, T, J, d)
        embd_query       = self.embd(query)           # (N, J, d)
        embd_query, _h   = self.query_rnn(embd_query) # (N, J, d)
        embd_query_ex  = embd_query.unsqueeze(1).expand(shape).contiguous() # (N, T, J, d)

        # Match-LSTM layer
        G = to_var(torch.zeros(bs, T, J, d)) # (N, T, J, d)

        wh_q = torch.bmm(embd_query, self.Wq.expand(bs, d, d)) # (N, J, d) = (N, J, d)(N, d, d)

        hidden     = to_var(torch.randn([bs, d])) # (N, d)
        cell_state = to_var(torch.randn([bs, d])) # (N, d)
        # TODO bidirectional
        H_r = [hidden]
        for i in range(T):
            wh_p_i = torch.bmm(embd_context[:,i,:].clone().unsqueeze(1), self.Wp.expand(bs, d, d)).squeeze() # (N, 1, d) -> (N, d)
            wh_r_i = torch.bmm(hidden.unsqueeze(1), self.Wr.expand(bs, d, d)).squeeze() # (N, 1, d) -> (N, d)
            sec_elm = (wh_p_i + wh_r_i).unsqueeze(1).expand(bs, J, d) # (N, J, d)

            G[:,i,:,:] = F.tanh( (wh_q + sec_elm).view(-1, d) ).view(bs, J, d) # (N, J, d) # TODO bias

            attn_i = torch.bmm(G[:,i,:,:].clone(), self.w.expand(bs, d, 1)).squeeze() # (N, J)
            attn_query = torch.bmm(attn_i.unsqueeze(1), embd_query).squeeze() # (N, d) 
            z = torch.cat((embd_context[:,i,:], attn_query), 1) # (N, 2d)

            hidden, cell_state = self.match_lstm_cell(z, (hidden, cell_state)) # (N, d), (N, d)
            H_r.append(hidden)
        H_r = torch.stack(H_r, dim=1) # (N, T, d)

        indices = self.ptr_net(H_r) # (N, M, T) , M means (start, end)
        return indices
```

Comment: I [changed the title](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/180984/revisions) to a different one that describes what the code does per [site goals](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._". Feel free to give it a different title if there is something more appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

> For example, I use `for loop` for generating sequence data (`for i in range(T):`).

The usual suggestion in such a case would be to [vectorize](//www.askpython.com/python-modules/numpy/vectorization-numpy) it. Let's take a look at what happens in your loop though. `sec_elm` relies on both `wh_p_i` and `wh_r_i`. And then `G` relies on `sec_elm`. Then `attn_i` relies on `G`, `attn_query` relies on `attn_i` and `z` relies on `attn_query`. It doesn't even stop there! Both `hidden` and `cell_state` rely on the output of that (and of their previously known values) and then `hidden` gets appended to `H_r`.

Can you still follow what's going on? Because with variable names like that, it's a challenge.

Your question is over 6 years old. It's not a bad question, but the code is dense and hard to follow. And thus hard to review. How can you optimize something you can barely follow? Can you understand today what you wrote back then? How would you explain what's going on to a colleague? Honestly I'm not sure how to start vectorizing that. But not all is lost.

`w` is a bad variable name. Even knowing you're working with Natural Language Processing, it could be short for `weight` or `word`. Which is a big difference. I know you probably meant weight. And I suppose `wq`, `qp` and `wr` are probably short for the weight of the query, weight of the passage and weight of the recurrent state. And then `wh_p_i` is what, the hidden weight of the passage of the index? The further I go, the more I'm putting assumptions on top of assumptions. Which is dangerous when you try to refactor code that has no tests.

You've attempted to clarify what you're doing with the comments behind the actions, such as `# (N, 1, d) -> (N, d)`. And that's definitely better than nothing. But your code is too complex to be summarized so succinctly. I see at least 4 batched matrix multiplications in the same `for` loop. If this is 4x a similar action, it could perhaps be given a meaningful name and be extracted to a function. Which would make it easier to see where the inefficiencies are.

Considering all the reshaping that's going on, I'd definitely check if [broadcasting](//pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/broadcasting.html#broadcasting-semantics) isn't an option for you and use [`torch.matmul`](//pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.matmul.html#torch.matmul) instead of `torch.bmm`.